# What are all of the emergency triggers?

Tags: civilization-6-rise-and-fall

I've seen/read examples of emergencies (for instance someone launching a nuclear weapon) but I haven't seen an exhaustive list anywhere.

**What are all of the emergencies?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Civilopedia there are currently five emergencies,

1. **Military Emergency** - A civilization that is leading in some victory type has just conquered another's city.
2. **City-State Emergency** - A civilization has captured and is occupying a city-state.
3. **Religious Emergency** - A civilization has converted the Holy City of another religion through a religious spread action.
4. **Nuclear Emergency** - A civilization has used a nuclear weapon on a city.
5. **Betrayal Emergency** - A civilization has declared war on another civilization with whom they had a high-level alliance.

Participation is based on their diplomatic relationship with the target (person who triggered it). In **most** of the emergencies the goal has to do with capturing the triggering civilization's cities. The city-state one is to liberate that city-state and the religious one is to convert that holy city to a different religion in time.